# Different values for String?

Tags: java

I'm newbie to java.

```
class Demo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1=new String("abc"); 
        String s2=new String("abc"); 
        String s3="xyz";
        String s4="xyz";

        System.out.println(s1==s2); //line 7
        System.out.println(s3==s4); //line 8
    }
}
```

I just don't understand why line 7 got false and line 8 got true.

I would be so grateful if someone explain me this.

Comment: Related: stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings

Answer (score -1):

When you use:

```
String s1=new String("abc"); 
String s2=new String("abc");
```

s1 and s2 are to different objects both created at runtime.

```
String s3="xyz";
String s4="xyz";
```

s3 and s4 are assigned at compilation time and java compiler stores only one copy of the string.

[Java intern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29)